# How to fix "Windows Security Warning" popup issue while extracting data from a website

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I have an application which extracts data from a website and loads it into a server table. When I run the application first time in a day it is showing a popup and asking for Yes/No input. How to overcome this popup as I wanted to auto schedule the application and run it without manual intervention.

```
Public Sub Resolve_Date()

    Dim XMLReq As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc = New mshtml.HTMLDocument
    'Dim htmlbody As HtmlDocument.body = New HTML
    Dim ObjXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim Table As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim Tr As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim Tc As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim Trs As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim URL As String
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

    URL = "https://tt.wiki.com/search?category=&assigned_group=3p-asin"
    XMLReq.open("GET", URL, False) '--pop up is appearing here
    XMLReq.send()
    If XMLReq.status <> 200 Then

       msgBox("Error" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText)
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim HTMLDoc1 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument = HTMLDoc

    HTMLDoc1.write("<html><body>test</body></html>")
    HTMLDoc1.close()
    HTMLDoc = HTMLDoc1
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    ''msgBox(HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML)
    'MsgBox(HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML)
    XMLReq = Nothing
    Table = HTMLDoc.getElementById("search_results")
    Trs = Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")


    For Each Tr In Trs
        --code to  insert data into Table
    Next Tr
```

Comment: And it's not a popup which you programmed? What question does it ask you exactly?

Comment: I havnt progammed the Pop-up, It is showing autiomaticlly when i run the application. The pop up is of "Winodws Security wanring" and the message in it is "This page is accessing information that is not under its control.This Poses a security risk. Do you want to continue? Yes No"

Comment: How to supress that Pop-up?

Comment: Maybe use the IE security settings to add that site to the trusted zone?

Comment: you've tagged vb.net but this looks like VB6 or VBA, or even VBScript code. I don't think this would work in .NET. Can you tell us what environment you're really using, please? Anyway I suspect the error is probably due to using an ActiveX component to download data. As MarkL says, you might want to try adding the site to your trusted zone in IE (since the XMLHTTP component you're using is effectively part of IE). See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45ef96a3-470c-431d-bb5d-34dceae0b3a7/error-this-page-is-accessing-information-that-is-not-under-its-control?forum=exceldev

Comment: Changing IE security settings not working for me @MarkL

Comment: It is Vb.net code only @ADyson ....Thank you for the reference Article but it is not helping me. Yes, I am Downloading data from a server and I have no control over it.

Comment: If this is genuinely VB.NET then why not use a class like WebClient or HttpClient to download your data, instead of something obsolete like the code above? It would remove the ActiveX problem. You are using code from 1999 not 2019

Comment: If you Google "VB.NET download file" you'll get plenty of examples using modern .NET libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I could do more if I knew what you were doing with the table... probably avoid the obsolte `MsHtml` API (`HTMLDocument` and friends) entirely. But with just the context we have, this is a rewrite that uses at least some more modern techniques and considerably simplifies the code.

```vb
Public Sub Resolve_Date() 
    Dim URL As String = "https://tt.wiki.com/search?category=&assigned_group=3p-asin" 
    Dim results As String = ""

    Try
        Using wc As New WebClient()
            results = wc.DownloadString(URL)
        End Using
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox($"Error{vbNewLine}{Ex.Message}")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim HTMLDoc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument()
    HTMLDoc.Write(results);

    Dim Table As mshtml.IHTMLElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("search_results")
    Dim Trs As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")

    Dim ObjXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

    For Each Tr As mshtml.IHTMLElement In Trs
         ' code to  insert data into Table
    Next Tr
End Sub
```